# Draw compound drawable outside EditText background

Tags: android, android-layout, compound-drawables

I'm trying to create an `EditText` with custom background, and a `compound drawable` to the left, but outside the background (currently it's appearing overlapped to the background); something like this.-

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: anything that the EditText will draw must be inside it's view bounds. Those are the rules. But nothing stops you from bending the rules by making a clever background for the View that will have the orange pre-draw.

Comment: Thanks @Budius. The screenshot may be confusing, actually that orange color is the background of the whole layout, so I would rather prefer not to add it as part of the EditText background. Curious thing is, that I started with an Horizontal LinearLayout with one ImageView (the mail icon) and the EditText, and a warning suggested me to replace it for a single EditText+Drawable, so I assumed there's a direct way to achieve this.

Comment: change my previous comment to 'transparent' instead of 'orange' then. But yeah, that warning doesn't know that you want the text box only around the text. I this case that you have a background might be safer instead of trying to adjust backgrounds in all different densities just use the horizontal LinearLayout and ignore the warning.

Comment: You're right, I'll stay with the LinearLayout's then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your background is the white box - then no, it's not possible to draw outside of the `TextView`'s bounds.

Although you can use a compound background, set the orange colour with the white box inside of it as your `TextView`'s background, then you'll be able to set the mailbox as the left drawable of your `TextView`.